# Error SOAP (SoapClient) in PHP 8.1 failed to load external entity

Tags: php, soap

I have a script in php that connect to a SOAP webservice. The problem is that in PHP 7.4 it works great (Tested in 3 different PC's with php 7.4), but when I try in a system with php 8.1 get this error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
> 'https://myurl.wsdl' : failed to
> load external entity
> "https://myurl.wsdl"

My script:

```
    <?php
$wsdl = "https://myurl.wsdl";

$context = stream_context_create(array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,
                            'verify_peer_name' => false, 
                            'allow_self_signed' => true,
                            )
                    )
                );

$header = array('local_cert' => 'file.pem', 
                'exceptions' => 1, 
                'trace' => true, 
                'stream_context' => $context
               );

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

try {  
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $header);  
    $result = $client->function();  
} 
catch(Exception $e) 
{ 
    $message = $e->getMessage(); 
    echo $message; 
    die();
}

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**
I did more text and maybe the problem is in Openssl 3 in Ubuntu 22.04 but not sure, because I have other enviroment with Openssl 1.1.1f and not working on php 8.1 but yes on 7.4

Waiting for some help.

Comment: Are you hosting myurl.wsdl locally and pointing to it by modifying your DNS? Because myurl.wsdl is not an existing hostname, as such, it makes sense PHP can't find any content on it.

Comment: I chaged the real url for post the script. The real url is different. But the script works in php 7.4. So no url error.

Comment: I'm using locally hosting but the enviroment works on 7.4 too

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem after updating to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I tried to access the site / document via Curl and it gave me a clue as the server is in DMZ it does not have access to internal DNS so after entring target site in /etc/hosts everything works as intended.

Answer (score -1):

I solved downgrading the security level on OpenSSL.conf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).